# Input masks in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, input, types

This answer is not in our books.

Which data types in MS Access do not support input masks?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the data types in table design. The InputMask property is not available for Autonumber, OLE Object, Attachment, Calculated, Hyperlink, Yes/No, Memo/LongText